# Kubernetes won't pick up new certificate, x509 certificate expired

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate-errors, kubeadm, x509

kubectl version Client Version: v1.20.4 Server Version: v1.20.15

At the end of January we renewed our external certificates that we use for the applications on the system (as opposed to the kubeadm certs for api/etcd etc these are all still fine). At the time, this all seemed to work successfully and we could see the new certificate in use when using the app as it is browser based, and restarting/redeploying pods and deployments worked all as expected

However a few weeks later the master and worker servers were all rebooted and since then our cluster has been unable to pull non-local images from our nexus, giving the following error when using 'kubectl describe pod [pod]', stopping them from fulling initializing

*Failed to pull image "pull.[servername]:30443/pwr-smallworld/fluent-bit:1.7.7": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://pull.[servername]:30443/v2/": **x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid**: current time 2024-03-04T15:44:48Z is after 2024-02-03T15:05:47Z*

The date the error is referring to is the expiry date of the old certificate that was replaced, and nothing we have tried so far has been able to convince kube to look at the new certificate

We have tried just about everything we can think of, but in short we have (excluding steps related to the app which is vendor specific)

1. updated all instances of the old certificate that we could find on the master server and nfs server with the new certificate, both the cert and the ca
2. re-deployed bifrost
3. regenerated secrets
4. We did do a kubeadm cert renewal to see if that helped, but it didn't and this change was later undone after a backup restoration.
5. we have we initialized kublet
6. we have rebooted the servers
7. we have re applied yaml files
8. we have followed the advice in existing stackoverflow questions that seem to have similar (but not the exact same) issues to no avail.

For reference this is the output of kubeadm certs check-expiration

[cert expiration picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fns8s.png)

We have also been using the following command to look for certs on the server in case we are simply missing a cert somewhere

find /home/ -type f -name ".pem" -print|egrep -v 'ca.crt$'|xargs -L 1 -t -i bash -c 'openssl x509 -noout -text -in {}|grep After'

But so far it has not found any cert, outside of a specific archive directory, that matches the expiry date reported in the error.

Happy to provide any information or try just about anything

Thank you in advance

Adam